# Redirect all request including homepage to /foo

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm using this code to redirect all request to `/foo`

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /foo [R,L]
```

This works on subpages like `example.com/1` but not on `example.com`. How can I make it work on `example.com` too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

seems that root is identified as a directory.

Comment: then check whether you modified htaccess at the root level and not in subdirectory

Comment: It is at root level inside `public_html`

Comment: then I suppose RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d might be a problem (root can be considered a directory), try removing it